# How to use GloVe word embedding model in ML.net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, word-embedding, ml.net

I'm new to Machine Learning and working on my master thesis using ML.net. I'm trying use glove model to vectorise a CV text, but finding it hard to wrap my head over the process. I have the Pipeline setup as below:

```
var pipeline = context.Transforms.Text.NormalizeText("Text", null,
            keepDiacritics: false, keepNumbers: false, keepPunctuations: false)
            .Append(context.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoWords("Tokens", "Text"))
            .Append(context.Transforms.Text.RemoveDefaultStopWords("WordsWithoutStopWords", "Tokens", Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text.StopWordsRemovingEstimator.Language.English))
            .Append(context.Transforms.Text.ApplyWordEmbedding("Features", "WordsWithoutStopWords",
                Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text.WordEmbeddingEstimator.PretrainedModelKind.GloVe300D));

var embeddingTransformer = pipeline.Fit(emptyData);

        var predictionEngine = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Input,Output>(embeddingTransformer);

        var data = new Input { Text = TextExtractor.Extract("/attachments/CV6.docx")};

        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(data);

        Console.WriteLine($"Number of features: {prediction.Features.Length}");

        Console.WriteLine("Features: ");
        foreach(var feature in prediction.Features)
        {
            Console.Write($"{feature}   ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
```

From what I've studied about vectorization, each word in the document should be converted into vector, but when I'm printing the features, I can see 900 features getting printed. Can someone explain how this works? There are very less examples and tutorials available about ML.net on internet.

Answer (score 1):

The vector of 900 features coming the `WordEmbeddingEstimator` is the min/max/average of the individual word embeddings in your phrase. Each of the min/max/average are 300 dimensional for the GloVe 300D model, giving 900 total.

The min/max gives the bounding hyper-rectangle for the words in your phrase. The average gives the standard phrase embedding.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/d1bf42551f0f47b220102f02de6b6c702e90b2e1/src/Microsoft.ML.Transforms/Text/WordEmbeddingsExtractor.cs#L748-L752

Answer (score 0):

GloVe is short for Global Vectorization.

GloVe is an unsupervised (no human labeling of the of the training set) learning method.  The vectors associated with each word are generally derived from each word's proximity with others in sentences.

Once you have trained your network (presumably on a *much* larger data set than a single CV/resume) then you can make interesting comparisons between words based on their absolute and relative "positions" in the vector space.  A much less computationally expensive way of developing a network to analyze e.g. documents is to download a pre-trained dataset.   I'm sure you've found this page (https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) which, among other things, will allow you to access pre-trained word embeddings/vectorizations.

Final thoughts:  I'm sorry if all of this is redundant information for you, especially if this really turns out to be a ML.net framework syntax question.  I don't know exactly what your goal is but

1. 900 dimensions seems like an awful lot for looking at CV's.  Maybe this is an ML.net default? I suspect that 300-500 will be more than adequate.  See what the pre-trained data sets provide.
2. If you only intend to train your network from zero on a single CV, then this method is going to be wholly inadequate.
3. Your best approach is likely to be a sort of transfer learning approach where you obtain a liberally licensed network that has been pre-trained on a massive data set in your language of interest (usually easy for academic work). Then perform additional training using a smaller, targeted group of training-only CV's to add any specialized words to the 'vocabulary' of your network.  Then perform your experimentation and analysis on a set of test CV's, which have never been used to train the network.